# Saving a log of console-mode Memtest86+ run

Tags: linux, memory, memtest86+

To debug mysterious failures with my workstation, I've booted it with an Ubuntu LiveCD and ran Memtest86+ in console mode. It found many errors. To isolate the defective sticks I need to send the lab a copy of the results report, indicating which addresses are bad.

The test has been running for almost two days now, probably because there is a lot of memory on the box - 32GB. There are well over a million errors at this point. How do I obtain an intermediary or final report as a file, so I can send it to the lab?